# Solving linear equations including semi-positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Can we solve the following for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A(x-a) + \lambda I_{\bullet i}&=0\\
I_{\bullet i}^Tx&=0,\,\,\,\text{or }(x_i=0)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $I_{\bullet i}$ is the i-th column of the identity matrix, and $i$ is a fixed and given index.
I did the following but cannot go further.

$x^TA(x-a) + \lambda x^TI_{\bullet i}=0$

$x^TA(x-a)=0$. Hence, $x- a \in N(A)$ or $x\in a+ N(A)$ and $\lambda=0$.

Also, $(x-a)^TAx=0$. Hence, $x \in N(A)$ and $Aa = \lambda I_{\bullet i}$ (I have no idea how to find $\lambda$ in this case).

Is there any other solutions for $x$ and consequently for $\lambda$?

Comment: Is $i$ given and fixed or should it hold for all $i$.

Comment: @ Andreas H: $i$ is given and fixed.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ also an unknown?

Comment: Why do you conclude $x-a\in N(A)$? All is known is that $x$ is perpendicular to $A(x-a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a,i$ are given quantities (but not $\lambda$), the problem has a solution when

- $Ay=-e_i$  ($e_i:=I_{\bullet,i}$) has a solution $y_0$, i.e., whether $e_i\in\mathrm{im}A$, since the first condition is equivalent to $Ay=-\lambda e_i$ (for some $\lambda$);

For any $b\in N(A)$ such that $e_i^T(y_0+b)\ne0$, let  $\lambda:=-e_i^Ta/e_i^T(y_0+b)$, so that $e_i^T(a+\lambda y_0+\lambda b)=0$, then the solution can be checked to be $$x=a+\lambda(y_0+b)$$ since $A(x-a)=\lambda Ay_0=-\lambda e_i$, and $e_i^Tx=e_i^T(a+\lambda y_0+\lambda b)=0$

[If $e_i^Ta=0$ then the solutions are $x=a+b$ for any $b\in N(A)$, since $(x-a)^TA(x-a)=-\lambda(x-a)^Te_i=0$ so $x-a\in N(A)$.]

---

If $e_i\notin\mathrm{im}(A)$, then the equation $Ay=-\lambda e_i$ can only be satisfied if $\lambda=0$ and $Ay=0$. Thus $x=a+y$ for some $y\in N(A)$. The other condition $e_i^Tx=0$ is then satisfied iff there is a non-empty intersection $(a+N(A))\cap e_i^\perp\ne\emptyset$. This is equivalent to $N(A)$ not being a subspace of $e_i^\perp$, i.e., $e_i\notin N(A)^\perp$.

Comment: I have two questions for you? What if $e_i \notin \mathrm{im}(A)$? Is your solution $x$ unique?

Comment: @Sepide The solution need not be unique since $b\in N(A)$ is almost arbitrary. This follows from the condition that $A$ is only positive *semi*-definite.

Comment: Can you please think about the case where $e_i \notin R(A)$ and let me know if we can find a solution in another format other than pseudo inverse mentioned by user1551?

Comment: @Sepide I answered that part in the last section.

Comment: Chrystomath: Why $(a+N(A))\cap e_i^\perp\ne\emptyset$ implies $e_i\notin N(A)^\perp$? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Sepide Both $N(A)$ and $e_i^\perp$ are subspaces. The first has some dimension $m$, while the second has dimension $n-1$ (a hyperplane). $a+N(A)$ is the same as $N(A)$ but displaced. Now any displaced subspace intersects a hyperplane unless it is "parallel" to it, that is, $N(A)\subseteq e_i^\perp$. Equivalently, $e_i\subseteq N(A)^\perp$.

Comment: I have posted a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905613/linear-equations-including-semi-positive-definite-matrix-and-vectors-of-standard) similar to this one, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

We write $e_i$ for $I_{\bullet i}$. There are two possibilities:

1. $e_i\not\in\operatorname{range}(A)$, i.e. $AA^+e_i\ne e_i$. Since the LHS of $A(x-a)=-\lambda e_i$ lies inside $\operatorname{range}(A)$ but $e_i$ does not, we must have $\lambda=0$. The system of equations can then be rewritten as
   $$
   \pmatrix{A\\ e_i^T}x=\pmatrix{Aa\\ 0}.
   $$
   It is solvable if and only if $x=\pmatrix{A\\ e_i^T}^+\pmatrix{Aa\\ 0}$ is a solution.
2. $e_i\in\operatorname{range}(A)$, i.e. $AA^+e_i=e_i$. Then $e_i^TA^+e_i\ne0$ and one may verify that $(\lambda, x)=\left(\frac{a_i}{e_i^TA^+e_i},\ a-\lambda A^+e_i\right)$ is a solution.

Comment: Can you please let me know what $A^+$ is? Is it pseudo inverse? If so, why are you using it, $A$ is a square matrix which is PSD? I could not follow.

Comment: @Sepide $A^+$ is the standard notation for the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $A$.

Comment: but $A$ is a square matrix, how can you have $A^+$?

Comment: @Sepide Every real or complex matrix has a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse. It has nothing to do with the size.

Comment: Can you elaborate on $e_i\not\in\operatorname{range}(A)$, i.e. $AA^+e_i\ne e_i$ and give me a link that explains the concepts you are using here because it is difficult for me to follow. I want to see the proof of what is clear to you:-)

Comment: @Sepide $AA^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$. The relevant stuffs can be found in any textbook that covers the "least squares method". [This Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linear_least-squares) may also be useful.